# warning in pointer assigning

Tags: c, pointers

I'm relatively new to C. And I wrote the following code:

```
#include "HashTable.h"

hashTable* newHashTable()
{
    hashTable* h = malloc(sizeof(hashTable));
    h -> size = TABLE_SIZE;
    h -> table = createTable(TABLE_SIZE);
    return h;
}

entry* createTable(int size)
{
    entry* table = malloc(sizeof(entry) * size);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
        (table + i) -> word = NULL; 
    return table;
}
```

and the content of HashTable.h is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define TABLE_SIZE 7
#define HASH_INCREMENT 3 // for efficient utilization of the hash table keep TABLE_SIZE * 2^n relative prime to HASH_INCREMENT
typedef struct entry_t
{
    char* word;
    int frequency;
}entry;
typedef struct hashTable_t
{
    int size;
    entry* table;
}hashTable;
```

When I try to compile this code (with some other code too) I get the following warning:

```
HashTable.c: In function ‘newHashTable’:
HashTable.c:7:13: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

Line 7 is actually the third line in newHashTable() function. I was looking at this for hours now. Please help me to resolve this warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ansii C assumes that any function that is called without having been declared returns `int`.

You should either declare `createTable` before `newHashTable`

```
entry* createTable(int size);

hashTable* newHashTable()
{
    /* implementation */
}

entry* createTable(int size)
{
    /* implementation */
}
```

or move its implementation before any calls

```
entry* createTable(int size)
{
    /* implementation */
}

hashTable* newHashTable()
{
    /* implementation */
}
```

or declare the functions in the header that also defines the struct

```
typedef struct entry_t
{
    char* word;
    int frequency;
}entry;
typedef struct hashTable_t
{
    int size;
    entry* table;
}hashTable;

entry* createTable(int size);
hashTable* newHashTable();
```

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. But why? That is my big question.

Comment: The third solution is the best. When C first encounters a function, it assumes that function returns an `int` unless the first encounter is a declaration. The first time it sees `createTable` is when you use it to assign its return value to `h->table`. At that time the compiler thinks the right hand side returns an `int` (by default) which is not a good thing to put in a pointer. And so it complains. With these solutions, the compiler "knows" that the RHS will return the correct pointer; so the warning goes away.

Comment: @UthpalaHerath See the first line of my answer.  A declaration of each function should appear before code that calls it.